# How is Quicksilver able to lift people?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe

In the two most recent X-men films, Quicksilver has moved people just in time to save them from bullets/explosions etc. How is he strong enough to do this? In the new movie he moves about a dozen people outside of the building and this must require extreme stamina (and strength?).

Anecdote: I remember taking a first aid course where we practiced moving an unconscious person and it was surprisingly difficult. It really does take two people or at least a tool to move a person.

Comment: If you apply enough force you can move a human quite easily. Force = mass * acceleration. Quicksilver (unsurprisingly) can accelerate a lot. Have you ever been tackled by someone running at full speed?

Comment: @TylerH tackling involves much different body mechanics than lifting and carrying someone. Do you really think bringing someone to the ground is as difficult as carrying them?

Comment: No, the mechanics are basically the same; deliver force via your muscles. The amount of force you can deliver is determined by your mass multiplied by your acceleration. So whether you're lifting, pushing, pulling, etc. the force you exert is determined by how massive you are and how quickly you exert the force. It's simple physics. If I swing my arm up into someone's crotch at 20mph, they'll get hurt. if I swing my arm up at 300mph into someone's crotch, they're gonna get lifted off the ground (assuming my arm remains intact).

Comment: Now, the various exact details of how they're lifted up and moved and placed precisely without experiencing extreme velocities or things like motion sickness probably involves some handwavium in the same category of how Tony Stark can survive being banged around inside his Iron Man suits.

Answer (score 4):

In the comics, Quicksilver does indeed have increased stamina.  From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_%28comics%29):

> Ability to move, speak and think at supersonic speeds, with enhanced stamina and durability

and

> Also, he has a fast metabolism and can heal more rapidly than the
>   average human.

His enhanced stamina can also be implied by the mere fact that he can run for sustained periods, rather than very short bursts, and his rapid healing means that if he carried someone out of the mansion, his arms would probably have recovered from the exertion on the way back to get the next person.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't know if physiologically speaking stamina is enough to carry a person, muscle is required too (but perhaps the average person has enough muscle to move an average sized person, just a little). Hmm.

Comment: I think when it comes to carrying people it's more about the length of time you're carrying them for- but if you can heal quicker, you can carry them further. I could probably carry someone much heavier than me, but not for very long.

Comment: @PointlessSpike that's the point I'm trying to make. Have you ever tried carrying someone much heavier? It may be possible if he's conscious and helping (e.g. jump on your back and hold on) but if their much heavier and just lying their, it's really really hard/impossible. This is why firefighters need to be big and fit.

Comment: @Celeritas- I'm not a superhero. Firefighters, as much as they are heroes, are not super. So it's not all that implausible taking his "enhanced stamina and durability" into account because it's the amount of time spent carrying them that's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

#### In the canon Marvel Comics Universe, Quicksilver (and his sister Wanda Maximoff) were initially believed to be mutants, members of Homo Sapiens Superior and the children of Magneto. It was later revealed that he actually was a normal child that was put through several experiments by the High Evolutionary which granted his powers.

[image]

- First introduced as a foe to the X-Men, Pietro Maximoff soon became an Avenger and atoned for his evil past. Initially, Pietro powers manifested with his ability to move at superhuman speed, with enhanced reflexes and stamina sufficient to move his body at supersonic speeds up to Mach one. He had a slight increase in his upper body strength and even greater stamina, strength and resilience in his lower body.

> - Quicksilver was originally presented as a mutant capable of moving and thinking at superhuman speeds. Originally capable of running at the speed of sound, exposure to the High Evolutionary's Isotope E made it possible for the character to run at supersonic speeds of up to Mach 10 and resist the effects of friction, reduced oxygen, and kinetic impact while moving at super-speeds.

- Quicksilver also has a fast metabolism and can heal more rapidly than the average human. The character's speed allows him to perform such feats as creating cyclone-strength winds and running up walls or across bodies of water. He can also cause vibrations in his body to transfer to solid material, and has superior agility and reflexes compared to other mutants.

[image]

Quicksilver in his X-men movie persona does not appear to have extreme levels of superhuman strength but appears to be strong enough to grab a person, accelerate them into his frame of movement, without harm, and then move them from their location to one nearby without serious or long-term injury.

- For many mutants, particularly ones whose powers are based in physical capacity, an increased level of strength is almost par for the course. Depending on when you view his character his upper body strength put him at the peak effectiveness for a Human at approximately 500 pounds lifting strength. His legs were rated at 1000 pounds.
- A normal Human, perhaps even two are well within his ability to life, move, tow or even throw a short distance due to his denser bone, muscle and cartilage. While such things may be difficult for normal Humans to accomplish, even trained one such as firefighters, Pietro's strength and ability to utilize his super-speed for throwing and catching gives him a great deal more latitude in how he moves people from dangerous areas.
- Note during the explosion scene in X-Men: Apocalypse, as Quicksilver starts running out of time, he is forced to get creative, throwing people out of windows and into swimming pools. This notes he was slowing down, possibly even getting tired, and had to begin to improvise to get everyone to safety.

#### Apocrypha

In the comics his origin has undergone a change due to licensing issues between Marvel and Sony and his mutant origin has been retconned away. Originally Pietro and his sister Wanda were believed to be the children of Magneto.

Answer (score -4):

Quinetic energy.

Quicksilver movement includes so much quinetic energy that moving a person should barely imply a glimpse of effort to him, compared to the effort to run at these speeds.

Comment: You mean kinetic?