# What power enables Quicksilver to move people at super-speed without killing them?

Tags: marvel, x-men, physics, quicksilver

I just watched X-Men Apocalypse, and there's an awesome scene of quicksilver clearing everyone out of an **exploding** building, but I want to know why he isn't ripping people's skeletons right out of their skins when he moves them at such amazing velocities.

[image]

In the previous movie it was established that he held onto people's heads so they didn't get "whiplash" but that doesn't seem to explain how he can move a person faster than an explosion without them suffering other effects of extreme acceleration (such as death).

Does Quicksilver emit some sort of *inertial dampening field* when he touches people that enables them to survive moving quickly?

Comment: The Speed Force protects them! Or something.

Comment: The supposed "duplicate" question actually asks if some one *would* get hurt, to which the highest voted answer is, "Yes, no one could survive that." This question is asking, "Why do they survive?" what is special about quicksilver's ability that prevents them from getting ripped apart like would in real life?

Comment: I've edited the question to better suit what you were asking but unfortunately, I can't vote to reopen since it's still a really close dupe of the other question. That being said, I don't really think any of the answers there actually address the question of whether there are powers at play. You might want to consider slinging a bounty onto the other question.

Comment: Not a dupe, but you might find this interesting; [How is Quicksilver able to lift people?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131417/how-is-quicksilver-able-to-lift-people?rq=1).